# DAX - count attributes for which FACT records do not exist

Tags: sql, ssas, dax, tabular, ssas-tabular

I am looking for a DAX measure that is equal to If i have in SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(NoDataValue WHEN -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM
(
SELECT Employee.EmployeeID, CASE WHEN FACT.EmployeeID IS NULL
                            THEN -1 
                            ELSE 1
                            END as NoDataValue
FROM Employee LEFT OUTER JOIN FACT
On Employee.EmployeeID = FACT.EmployeeID
) X
```

Essentially i want -1 when there is no data for an employee at the row level but when its aggregated i need count of NoDataValues (How many employees did not have data).
That is working fine at employee level with the measure i created

```
Annual Independence Compliance No Data:=
  Var NoData=
  SUM ( [NoDataValue] )
RETURN (IF (ISBLANK(NoData) , -1, NoData))
```

This looks like

[image]
But this is not aggregating the counts. I am having trouble of how to do that. This shows up as

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you SQL query is returning what you want but the query should look like below

```
SELECT SUM(case NoData WHEN -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NoDataCount
FROM
(
SELECT Employee.EmployeeID, CASE WHEN FACT.EmployeeID IS NULL
                            THEN -1 
                            ELSE 1
                            END as NoData
FROM Employee LEFT OUTER JOIN FACT
On Employee.EmployeeID = FACT.EmployeeID
) X
```

or

```
SELECT SUM(IIF(NoData = -1,1,0)) as NoDataCount
```

Comment: DAX doesn't have IIF construct ? and yes, the SQL query is only meant to show the COUNT of -1s at the top level and -1 in front of each employee at the employee level

Comment: IIF only applies if you are solving it through SQL to a specific version

Comment: Sorry if i wasnt clear, i am looking for a DAX measure, not SQL

Comment: if you can translate the right SQL query to Dax then that should solve your problem